# Using Casper JS to enter info on website

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

is there anyway to use Casper JS to to enter info, such as zip codes (about 10k) to a tool called map anything from Salesforce.

Would be great to automate this, and I thought CasperJS might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a website you can automate it using casper, however, this is not very efficient and should be used as a last resort. If the app is designed for this they will usually have a bulk upload feature you can use or contact support to see if they can help you load your data into the salesforce environment. Also, i would expect a mapping tool to be able to handle zip codes out of the box.